# How to return an array matching a certain criteria in Excel?

Tags: arrays, excel

I'm trying to parse an XML file in Excel, which is a Japanese dictionary. It contains several translations of each entry into different languages, and some entries have multiple translations per language. I want to write a formula that finds all of the translations by their language code, returns them as an array, and concatenates them using a `TEXTJOIN` formula. But I don't know how to go about this in Excel.

In Google Sheets, this would be easily solved by a FILTER function, but I can't use Sheets as there's too much data, and I haven't managed to get access to the beta FILTER function yet.

In the below picture, I'm trying to return the values in the `<gloss xml:lang*>` column, by searching for the values in the `lang` column. So for example, I want to return all values which have a "dut" next to them, and concatenate those into a single line using `TEXTJOIN`.

Any idea how I could go about doing this?

[image]

Comment: Try putting `=IF(H1047878="","",G1047878&T1047879)`in T1047878. and drag downwards.. does it work?

Comment: No, that won't work because I'm trying to find the elements in the H column which match the three letter codes from T2:AA2 ("dut", "ger", "rus" and so on.) So I want to find all of the instances that match this code, then lookup to the cell next to it, then return all of those results in an array and concatenate it into a single cell.

Comment: Can you share exactly how the intended full output look like? (with its desired location)

Comment: It's okay, I've just solved the problem by downloading the updated version of Excel which has the FILTER function. I couldn't work out how to download said version for a silly reason. Now I've achieved the functionality I want, I'll probably post the answer soon.

Comment: Please post it as answer... As it will be removing this question from the "unanswered" list.. & it will benefit others.. /(^_^)

Comment: That's done. . .

Comment: Congrats.. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by downloading the `FILTER` function. This is part of the Office Insider program, which releases Beta features if you choose to participate. You can access the Insider program by going to File > Account > Office Insider. Then to update your Office version go to File > Account > Office Updates to install the Insider update.

To filter the list by the "lang" column the formula looked like:

```
=FILTER([range in H column], [range in I column]=T$2)
```

I haven't specified either range because I used a formula-defined range using the `INDIRECT` function to avoid filtering through a million rows. The H range is what I want in the results of the filter, the I range is what I want to filter by - the "lang" code. T$2 represents the "lang" code, in this case "dut", and when I copy it across it will filter by each of the 8 lang codes in Row 2.

Then I used `TEXTJOIN` to combine it the array result into one column using the comma separator:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, FILTER(...))
```